# How to assert that a list of variables is real in a nice and clean way

Tags: replacement, assumptions

You can use the function `Element` to say e.g. $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}$ via `Element[x | y | z, Reals]`.

Now if I have a list of elements and want to say that they are all real I could do:

```
list = Array[x @ # &, 8]
Element[#, Reals]& /@ list /. List -> And
```

However, that seems unnecessarily complicated. Is there an easier way? Easier meaning shorter but also clear and easy to understand.

Comment: Instead of `/.List->And` you can just `Apply` `And`: `And@@(Element[ #, Reals ]& /@ list)`.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do, but things like `Assuming[{x, y} ∈ Reals, (* stuff *)]` work, FYI.

Comment: Ah ok, didn't know that! In the documentation it was only with the `|` or `{x, y, z} \[Element] Ball[]`

Comment: Also a list of assumptions should work with Simplify and the like ... so `Element[#, Reals] & /@ list` should be enough.

Comment: The `FullForm` of `{x, y} ∈ Reals` is `(x | y) ∈ Reals`, so `list ∈ Reals` is by far the "nicest and cleanest" way to write your assertion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straight-forward adaptation of your code is the following:

```
list = Array[x, 8];
Apply[And, Element[#, Reals]& /@ list
(* x[1] ∈ Reals && x[2] ∈ Reals && x[3] ∈ Reals && x[4] ∈ Reals && x[5] ∈ Reals && x[6] ∈ Reals && x[7] ∈ Reals && x[8] ∈ Reals *)
```

Also, you can do

```
Element[Alternatives @@ list, Reals]
```

---

You can also do (according to `GuessWhoItIs`),

```
list ∈ Reals
```

---

Often, lists of assumptions are fine, so you can use (according to `Bichoy`)

```
Element[#, Reals] & /@ list
```